# How to get MainActivity for an Intent created in another class in Xamarin.Droid project?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to set alarm for Xamarin.Droid project. Use DependencyService for platform-specific functions, define an interface with the signature of these functions

```
namespace ExampleProgram.Droid
{
    public interface IRunAlarm
    {
        Intent setIntent();
        ...
    }
}
```

and class with implementation.

```
 [assembly: Dependency(typeof(ExampleProgram.Droid.RunAlarm))]
    namespace ExampleProgram.Droid
    {
        public class RunAlarm: MainActivity, IRunAlarm
        {
            public Intent setIntent()
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
                return i;
            }
            ...
        }
    }
```

But, when I run the program, an exception occurs:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
```

An exception occurred on this line:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="3" android:versionName="3" package="com.example.exampleprogram">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:label="exampleprogram" android:icon="@drawable/appicon"></application>
</manifest>
```

How to handle this exception and how to get MainActivity correctly in this case?

Comment: can you post your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes,  @DanielAndujar. I added

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i will try to reproduce it myself and let you know